# How can I manage make targets that don't have suffixes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a make file that generates multiple targets.  Something like:

```
target-a: target-a.src target-include.src
        @$(BUILD_TOOL) -f $< -o $@
target-b: target-b.src target-include.src
        @$(BUILD_TOOL) -f $< -o $@
target-c: target-c.src target-include.src
        @$(BUILD_TOOL) -f $< -o $@
```

The actual build process (abbreviated as `$(BUILD_TOOL)` above) is a multiple line thing involving compilers, scripts and various whatnot, but suffice to say, the build process acts on the first target dependency (`$<`) and produces the output target (`$@`).

This is quite unwieldly.  **Would what I've got below be considered a *safe* way to replace the above (using a pattern rule that doesn't have a suffix)?**

```
all: target-a target-b target-c

% : %.src target-include.src
        @$(BUILD_TOOL) -f $< -o $@
```

The make tool is GNU, and I'm content to use it's powerful extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `target` is a literal string, renierpost's solution is very good. If it isn't (or even if it is) this will work:

```
TARGETS := target-a target-b target-c

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): % : %.src target-include.src
    @$(BUILD_TOOL) -f $< -o $@
```

Note that this rule will not build targets you did not intend, not even `target-include`.

Comment: How could I ammend the makefile so that it would make the target-include.src? Would `#(TARGETS): target-include.src` immediately followed by `$(TARGETS): % : %.src target-include.src ...` be acceptable?

Comment: That would be *acceptable* (i.e. legal) but it would do nothing. Just put in a rule for `target-include.src` and Make will rebuild `target-include.src` when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the rest of your Makefile, but in principle this should work,
if all files are in one directory.

It's better practice to use extensions on your targets.

Is `target` a literal string?  In that case, you can be more specific
(and speed up rule application a tiny little bit, but it's fast already) by using

```
all: target-a target-b target-c

target-% : target-%.src target-include.src
    @$(BUILD_TOOL) -f $< -o $@
```

GNU make's advanced syntax will come into play if you want to automatically deduce the names of `target-a target-b target-c` from the `target-*.src` filenames on the filesystem or something similar.